# Problems with centering scene

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl

I have to display stl models with openGL. (SharpGL.) I'd like to set the initial view, so that the model is at the center of the screen and approximately fills it. I've calculated the bounding cube of the models and set the view like this: (sceneBox is a Rect3D - it stores the location of the left-back-bottom corner and the sizes)

```
// Calculate viewport properties
double left = sceneBox.X;
double right = sceneBox.X + sceneBox.SizeX;
double bottom = sceneBox.Y;
double top = sceneBox.Y + sceneBox.SizeY;

double zNear = 1.0;
double zFar = zNear + 3 * sceneBox.SizeZ;

double aspect = (double)this.ViewportSize.Width / (double)this.ViewportSize.Height;

if ( aspect < 1.0 ) { 
    bottom /= aspect;
    top /= aspect;
} else {
    left *= aspect;
    right *= aspect;
}

//  Create a perspective transformation.
gl.Frustum(
    left / ZoomFactor, 
    right / ZoomFactor,
    bottom / ZoomFactor, 
    top / ZoomFactor,
    zNear, 
    zFar);

//  Use the 'look at' helper function to position and aim the camera.
gl.LookAt(
    0, 0, 2 * sceneBox.SizeZ,           
    sceneBox.X + 0.5 * sceneBox.SizeX, sceneBox.Y + 0.5 * sceneBox.SizeY, sceneBox.Z - 0.5 * sceneBox.SizeZ,    
    0, 1, 0);
```

This works nice with my small, hand-made test model: (it has a box size of 2*2*2 units)

[image: Good view]

This is exactly what I want. (The yellow lines show the bounding box)

But, when I load an stl model, which is about 60*60*60 units big, I get this:

[image: Bad view]

It's very small and too far up.

What should I change to make it work?

Here's the full thing: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17798054/program.zip

You can find this model in the zip as well. The quoted code is in `KRGRAAT.SZE.Control.Engine.GLEngine.UpdateView()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem are the arguments you are using in lookAt function. If you have calculated bounding cube all you need to do is to place it in the distance (eyeZ) from the camera of

**sizeX/tan(angleOfPerspective)**

where sizeX is width of Quad of which cube is built, angleOfPerspective is first parameter of GlPerspective of course having centerX == posX == centreX of the front quad and centerY == posY == centreY of the front quad and frustum is not necessary

lookAt reference http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml

Comment: No problem. ps. I really deteste dividing by tg, but this seems to be the easiest way to do it with using LookAt function.

Answer (score 0):

So, to clarify Arek's answer, this is how I fixed it:

```
// Calculate viewport properties
double zNear = 1.0;
double zFar = zNear + 10 * sceneBox.SizeZ; // had to increase zFar

double aspect = (double)this.ViewportSize.Width / (double)this.ViewportSize.Height;

double angleOfPerspective = 60.0;
double centerX = sceneBox.X + 0.5 * sceneBox.SizeX;
double centerY = sceneBox.Y + 0.5 * sceneBox.SizeY;
double centerZ = sceneBox.Z + 0.5 * sceneBox.SizeZ;

//  Create a perspective transformation.
gl.Perspective( // swapped frustum for perspective
    angleOfPerspective / ZoomFactor, // moved zooming here
    aspect,
    zNear,
    zFar);

//  Use the 'look at' helper function to position and aim the camera.
gl.LookAt(
    centerX, centerY, sceneBox.SizeX / Math.Tan(angleOfPerspective), // changed eye position
    centerX, centerY, -centerZ,
    0, 1, 0);
```